# Spacecurve of intersection between surfaces

Tags: vectors, maple, intersection-theory

### Problem

The spacecurve of intersection between the surfaces $opp$ & $\alpha$ (above z=3) has to be found, i.e. the intersection of the blue and green surface, above the red pane (z=3).

### Plots

[image: 3D Plot]
[image]

### Details

$$opp: z=10e^{-x^2-\frac{1}{4}.y^2}$$
 $$\alpha: z=2x+6$$

- $x=t$
- $z=2t+6$

equating them to eachother, to find y:
$$10e^{-x^2-\frac{1}{4}.y^2}=2x+6$$
applying $ln$ on both sides
$$y=\sqrt{-4(\frac{ln(2t+6)}{ln(10)}+t^2})$$
Spacecurve:
$$r(t)=<t,\sqrt{-4(\frac{ln(2t+6)}{ln(10)}+t^2}),2t+6>$$

However, maple comes up with the following error:

> Warning, unable to evaluate the function to numeric values in the region

### Maple-code

```
restart;
assume(t,'real'):
curve := [t, sqrt((-ln(2*t+6)/ln(10)+t^2)*4), 2*t+6]:
with(plots):
spacecurve(curve,t=1..10);
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Hint: What happens if $t = 1$ or $t = 2$?

Comment: @Kaster, i get a complex value for the y. Does this mean i need to get the absolute value?

Comment: No, it means that you need to restrict values for $t$ so that all expressions have real values.

Comment: @Kaster, I've restricted all expressions to real values. But i'm still getting the same warning.

Comment: How did you do that? Can you edit your question accordingly then? Because I still see that $t = 1..10$. You should get restriction on the $t$.

Comment: @Kaster, i've updated the Maple code.

Comment: First of all, parametric equation for the $y$ component you found is wrong. Second, I don't think you understand what I meant by restriction on $t$. Simple $t \in \mathbb R$ is not enough. It should be more stronger than that. See my answer, which I'll post later today.

Comment: @Kaster, don't put effort in the problem. I made a mistake with the alpha-plane. It had to be defined as $z=2x+6$ instead of $z=2x-6$. I'm very sorry! I edited in the post. I'm very sorry!

Comment: So, you've revised the defn of alpha to now be `2*t+6` rather than the original `2*t-6`. Ok. But you also revised and added the "above `z=3`" condition. Are you sure that you have it right yet?

Comment: @acer, I have done another edit of the post. I added the "above z=3" so it's clear that it's not about the intersection that takes place between $x=-2$ and $x=-4$. I'm very sorry I wasn't more careful with the problem description. But already a big thank you for the help. The intersection-plot you mentioned, is a good tool for visualization! I'll add the intersection plot to the topic too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the methods provided by the answers to solve the plotting of the spacecurve.

```
restart;
with(plots):
opp := z = 10*exp(-x^2-y^2/4):
alpha := z= 2*x +6:

ySolutions:=solve(eq,y);
subs({x=t},[ySolutions]):
ySolutions:=%:
y1:=ySolutions[1]:
y2:=ySolutions[2]:

curve1:=[t,y1,2*t+6]:
curve2:=[t,y2,2*t+6]:

#other way to solve the equation for y:
S := solve( eq, y );
#Im-Re plot of S[1] to visualize the boundaries to search for zeros
plot([Re,Im](S[1]), x=-10..10, color=[red,blue]);

xLzero:=fsolve(S[1]=0,x,{x=-2..0});
                         -0.9422426330
xRzero:=fsolve(S[1]=0,x,{x=0..1});
                          0.5783829968
sc1:=spacecurve(curve1,t=xLzero..xRzero):
sc2:=spacecurve(curve2,t=xLzero..xRzero):
display([sc1,sc2]);
```

#### Im-Re plot of S(1)

[image: Re-Im plot of S[1]]

#### The Spacecurve

[image: Spacecurve plot]

Comment: @acer, I used the methods you provided to solve my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

```
restart:

opp := z = 10*exp(-x^2-y^2/4);

                           /  2   1  2\
                 z = 10 exp|-x  - - y |
                           \      4   /

alpha := z= 2*x -6;

                      z = 2 x - 6

eq := eval(z,opp)=eval(z,alpha);

                    /  2   1  2\          
              10 exp|-x  - - y | = 2 x - 6
                    \      4   /          

S := solve( eq, y );

                     (1/2)                        (1/2)
  /  2     /1     3\\          /  2     /1     3\\     
2 |-x  - ln|- x - -||     , -2 |-x  - ln|- x - -||     
  \        \5     5//          \        \5     5//     


plot([Re,Im](S[1]), x=2.999..3.001, color=[red,blue]);
```

[image]

The imaginary components of `S[1]` and `S[2]` are nonzero except within a tight range of x. See the blue curve above. We can find the upper value numerically (approximately).

```
high := fsolve(S[1],x);

                      3.000614777
```

Now we can form the spacecurve in two parts, `Pc1` and `Pc2` below.

```
Pc1 := plots:-spacecurve([x, S[1], eval(z,alpha)], x=3..high,
                         labels=[x,y,z], color=green):

Pc2 := plots:-spacecurve([x, S[2], eval(z,alpha)], x=3..high,
                         labels=[x,y,z], color=green):
```

Optionally, we can also display the two surfaces alongside the green spacecurve.

```
Poa := plot3d( [eval(z,opp), eval(z,alpha)],
               x=3..high, y=-12 .. 12, color=[gold,grey] ):

plots:-display( Poa, Pc1, Pc2, view=[default,default,0..0.0015]);
```

[image]

I used a restricted viewing range for y. You'd need to use higher working precision to get the y values with much greater absolute value. However,

```
limit( S[1], x=3, right );

                        infinity

limit( S[2], x=3, right );

                       -infinity
```

Note also that there is a dedicated command, [plots:-intersectplot](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=plots/intersectplot), for plotting the intersection of two surfaces in modern Maple.

Let's use it first without attempting hard to figure out a special range for x (or y).

```
restart:
opp := z = 10*exp(-x^2-y^2/4):
alpha := z= 2*x -6:

plots:-intersectplot(eval(z,opp), eval(z,alpha),
                     x=-12..12, y=-12..12, grid=50);
```

[image]

And now that we can restrict the range for x, to see the curve better,

```
plots:-intersectplot(eval(z,opp), eval(z,alpha),
                     x=2.999..3.001, y=-12..12, grid=50);
```

[image]

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I just saw that the alpha-pane is defined wrong in question. I kept using the wrong equations myself, the alpha-plane had to be $z=2x+6$ instead of $z=2x-6$.

Comment: Well, then re-do the computations, and notice that your now revised surfaces intersect in more than one way. You can also try it with the following, which you can also display with the actual surfaces. `plots:-intersectplot(eval(z,opp),eval(z,alpha),x=-4..2,y=-12..12,grid=50)`